# Question about inductors in the form of magnetic fields

Tags: capacitor, inductor

Could you please explain this sentence: Inductors build up energy in the form of magnetic fields, and become more conductive.

Comment: It’s true that inductors store energy as magnetic fields, but the ‘more conducive’ part could be misleading.  When a DC voltage is applied, the amount of current that the inductor allows to flow starts at zero and then increases linearly with time until the inductor’s core saturates, in other words it’s as magnetised as it can be, at this point the inductor starts to behave like a piece of wire, and allows a large current to flow.

Comment: Where did you read this sentence? Can you put a link to the article? Sometimes the previous or the following sentence(s) may need to be taken into account as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please explain this sentence: Inductors build up energy in the form of magnetic fields,

Inductors store energy. The best model we have for the physical world is that it's based on 'fields', the magnetic field being one of them. Nobody knows what a field 'really' is (or what 'really' means), but you can feel the *effect* of a magnetic field when you bring two magnets together, one in each hand. It's something that creates a force between the magnets, and stores energy. It can be described by a few numbers, to predict accurately what happens at the terminals of an inductor.

> and become more conductive.

It's difficult to know what the author was even thinking of in this phrase. The inductor does not become more conductive. In fact, the flowing current heats the wires, which will usually make it slightly less conductive.

Is there any other interpretation of the author's intent? Perhaps this belongs on the Puzzling stack, 'what was the author thinking?'.

The use of 'build up' in the previous phrase suggests that current is increasing, and so the inductor is creating a back EMF. Incidentally, the current flowing against this back EMF is doing work on the inductor, that work storing energy in its magnetic field.

This back EMF could be thought of as making the inductor 'less conductive', as without it, more current could flow from a typical power source.

Now if the inductor is cored, with ferrite or iron, this will eventually saturate at a high enough field. The inductance will then reduce significantly, which will reduce the back EMF, which might be considered to make the inductor 'more conductive'. But that's a lot of unstated assumptions to make.

You will get a better answer if you post exactly where and in what context this sentence occurred.